Scanning via WIA with a Brother MFC Device
I have been struggling with a problem regarding the Feeder of my MFC-7360N.
I am coding a Windows Forms Application in C# with .NET 8 and WIA v2 (without any NuGet Package, just the COM Reference). The app is supposed to scan from the Brother Device and I wanted to implement automatic detection of wether to use the Feeder or the Flatbed using the Document Handling Status Property. However, the value of this property is always 3, no matter if there is actually a document in the feeder or not.
I already tried setting Page Size, Extent as well as Resolution to match the used DIN A4 paper standard (like another Stackoverflow question I found was recommending) but it still just gives me 3.
Does anyone have any experience with this?
Thanks in advance
